# UBuntu 12.04 Broadcom 4313 Wireless Problem

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I am using Ubuntu 32bit and 64 bit. In Ubuntu 32 bit I was successful in working wirelessly, but slow.

In Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, I tried all: Activating Broadcom STA wirelss drivers no luck, deactiving them and installing with new version, many tries but wirelss didn't work.

Sometimes, my WLAN card doesn't detected at all - *no* network devices available in the network manager.

I tried blacklisting and other resources that are available on the web. No luck.

On 32 bit: Slow drivers worked for me: `STA broadcom-wireless bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6_i386.deb`

But 64 bit version of drivers `bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb` didn't work on machine.

I am tired of trying and Ubuntu should take care of such pathetic issues.

Don't know why they make things worse after updates. In ubuntu 11.10 everything was working fine.

```
lshw
network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 01
                serial: 08:ed:b9:e2:b8:39
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.112 ip=10.100.28.51 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the native driver brcmsmac instead of the proprietary STA driver. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Now let's check any blacklists you added:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

If you blacklisted brcmsmac or bcma, please remove those lines. Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot and tell us if it is working now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but above doesn't worked for me.

Comment: Finally, tired up of ubuntu, i was here at ubuntu because there is no need to install drivers etc and it save time but if you get stuck in something, then time taken and pain is much much higher than windows and drivers installation.